# How to get typed $data with class based Vue component

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a component something like this:

```
interface Data {
  currentDirectory: string;
}

@Component({
})
export default class TileMemory extends Vue {

  public data(): Data {
    return {
      currentDirectory: '/',
    };
  }

  public clearDirectory() {
    this.$data.currentDirectory = '';
  }
}
```

This appears to work, however `this.$data.currentDirectory` has the type `any`, not `string` even though I annotated the return type of `data()`. I've tried various things - putting `data()` in `@Component({})` instead (where should it go? nobody seems to know), using `this.currentDirectory` instead (does not compile).

Is there a way to get proper types for the `data` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `$data` is a [`Record<string, any>`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/731e4d0/types/vue.d.ts#L33), so its property values will always be type `any`.

Assuming you're using [`vue-class-component`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) (the default in a Vue CLI project), you don't need to declare the `data()` method. You could simply [declare  initial data as class properties](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/blame/master/README.md#L21) like this:

```js
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class TileMemory extends Vue {
  currentDirectory = '/'

  public clearDirectory() {
    this.currentDirectory = ''
  }
}
```

If for some reason you prefer using the `data()` method with the `Data` interface, you could achieve type safety with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```js
export default class TileMemory extends Vue {
  //...

  public clearDirectory() {
    (this.$data as Data).currentDirectory = ''
  }
}
```

...or using a getter (convenient if you have many usages):

```js
export default class TileMemory extends Vue {
  //...

  get $$data() {
    return this.$data as Data
  }

  public clearDirectory() {
    this.$$data.currentDirectory = ''
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the function data to a computed property, something like this:

```
interface Data {
  currentDirectory: string;
}

@Component({
})
export default class TileMemory extends Vue {

  get data(): Data {
    return {
      currentDirectory: '/',
    };
  }

  public clearDirectory() {
    this.data.currentDirectory = '';
  }
}
```